# Django .get() raises DoesNotExist error without explicit '__exact' lookup

Tags: django, orm

I've faced with issue, which I cannot neither understand nor 'google', while followed steps from "Practical Django Projects" book.

The example of view code below should return specific Entry object (I omitted unnecessary part), but it raises "DoesNotExist: Entry matching query does not exist" error:

```
...
return render_to_response('weblog/entry_detail.html',
                          {'entry':Entry.objects.get(pub_date__year=pub_date.year,
                                           pub_date__month=pub_date.month,
                                           pub_date__day=pub_date.day,
                                           slug=slug)
```

(I confirmed that target object indeed exists, etc.)

When I replaced .get() with filter() method, it returned me queryset with my target object.

After some 'hitting-the-wall' sessions, I managed to make .get() call work when replaced

```
   slug=slug
```

with

```
   slug__exact=slug
```

I cannot get the difference between these two. Seems to me, Django's docs clearly state that in such case '__exact' is implied ([Django 1.6, "Making queries"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups))

I also cannot check the actual SQL query which Django ran in the .get() cases to compare with SQL query used with .filter() method (the result is either object, not queryset, or raised exception).

So, I actually have 2 workarounds (filter()[0] to get single object, or '__exact'), but I want to understand the weird behavior with .get() method.

My **questions** are:

1. Did I misunderstand documentation about '__exact' implication in my case?
2. If no, isn't my problem a Django/DB bug?
3. Is there a way to check the actual SQL query which Django has performed, when result of query is not a queryset object?

Thank you!

**Note**: I run Django 1.6.1 / Python 2.7.3 / MySQL 5.5.33

**Update**: I installed suggested **django-debug-toolbar** and was able to compare queries for .get() call with & w/o '__exact' lookup. The only difference that I see between these queries, is the order of 'AND' conditions, so still have no clue what's going on:

1. slug=slug:

   SELECT `weblog_entry`.`id`, `weblog_entry`.`title`, `weblog_entry`.`excerpt`, `weblog_entry`.`body`, `weblog_entry`.`pub_date`, `weblog_entry`.`excerpt_html`, `weblog_entry`.`body_html`, `weblog_entry`.`author_id`, `weblog_entry`.`slug`, `weblog_entry`.`status`, `weblog_entry`.`enable_comments`, `weblog_entry`.`featured` FROM `weblog_entry` WHERE (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CONVERT_TZ(`weblog_entry`.`pub_date`, 'UTC', 'UTC')) = 2 AND `weblog_entry`.`pub_date` BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and '2014-12-31 23:59:59' AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM CONVERT_TZ(`weblog_entry`.`pub_date`, 'UTC', 'UTC')) = 2 AND `weblog_entry`.`slug` = '3rd-entry' )
2. slug__exact=slug:

   SELECT `weblog_entry`.`id`, `weblog_entry`.`title`, `weblog_entry`.`excerpt`, `weblog_entry`.`body`, `weblog_entry`.`pub_date`, `weblog_entry`.`excerpt_html`, `weblog_entry`.`body_html`, `weblog_entry`.`author_id`, `weblog_entry`.`slug`, `weblog_entry`.`status`, `weblog_entry`.`enable_comments`, `weblog_entry`.`featured` FROM `weblog_entry` WHERE (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CONVERT_TZ(`weblog_entry`.`pub_date`, 'UTC', 'UTC')) = 2 AND `weblog_entry`.`pub_date` BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and '2014-12-31 23:59:59' AND `weblog_entry`.`slug` = '3rd-entry' AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM CONVERT_TZ(`weblog_entry`.`pub_date`, 'UTC', 'UTC')) = 2)

**Note**: I've tried to execute these queries manually from mysql console and they both selected target entry;

**Update2**: I've changed title to point on the problem more precisely.

Comment: django-debug-toolbar is a super easy way to see what queries (and more) are firing: https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar

Comment: Thank you for advice! I was able to check resulting queries for .get() method with & w/o '__exact' lookup using django-debug-toolbar: the only difference that I see is the order in which 'AND' conditions are composed. Updated post.

Comment: Have you tried these queries directly in the db to see if they give different results?

Comment: Yes, they both select target entry, updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let me speak for collective unconscious.

> Did I misunderstand documentation about '__exact' implication in my case?

No, you got it right. Let me quote [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups):

> As a convenience when no lookup type is provided (like in
>   Entry.objects.get(id=14)) the lookup type is assumed to be exact.

And since you observe something that contradicts requirements, answer to the next question is:

> If no, isn't my problem a Django/DB bug?

Yes, it is a bug. Me and whole Django community will be grateful if you describe steps to reproduce and [file an issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket)

> Is there a way to check the actual SQL query which Django has
>   performed, when result of query is not a queryset object?

Looks you already got the answer :)